# Why is $(document).ready not firing for me?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In a php file i have used `include` to include the following js.php file
and prior to that i have included the jquery file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
     alert("hello");
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. Why? when I skip the $(document).ready function it works.

But i need jquery code inside. what is wrong?

Comment: Can you post your PHP code as well?

Comment: Post the errors you receive. If you are using firefox the error console can be access via 'Tools > Error Console'

Comment: Are you using any other javascript frameworks? Is the path to your jquery file correct?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The most likely answer, based on what you have said, is that the core jQuery file is not actually included correctly in the page.
You need something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Chances are, this is missing or typed incorrectly.

Comment: I have seen this same exact question numerous times - and it was nearly always the jQuery <script> tag like this occurance.  Even done it myself :)

Comment: Using the Google loader can help avoid these kinds of typos, as well as automatically pulling down an updated version of jQuery (if desired):

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
  google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>

Answer (score 27):

Another cause that will silently fail, and all remaining callbacks never called:

```
$(document).ready(null);
```

So check if you have variables or syntax errors that return null. Like this one:

```
$(document).ready(function($){}(jQuery));
```

Notice that the function above is called instantly and undefined is returned.

Comment: For example me, I had used previously undefined variable as a selector input in `$().each` loop callback.

Answer (score 4):

1. Check whether jQuery is loaded correctly.
2. Look at the browser's progress bar: it may be loading some counters and the document is not ready until they're loaded: this often happens when external resources are slow.
3. Try `$(function(){ alert(...); });` just in case...
4. Check whether you have JS errors prior to this onload binding. Use Firefox's FireBug plugin to check it out.

Comment: firebug says that 
  $(document).ready(function(){
is not defined...is it something wrong with my jquery file?

Comment: Are you using Mootools?... if so, make sure you have Jquery set for compatibility

Comment: if it says $(document).... is not a function that means that 1) another library is capturing the $, or that jQuery did not load properly.

Answer (score 3):

Also look out how you define the jquery include tag. It seems for some reason you need to open and close the tag with two seperate tags. Using one tag with closing it seems not to work:

Works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem too and this is what I did.

Ensure that **document.ready** is placed **after** the callback function is defined in your javascript file.

Here, init is not defined yet when document.ready is being parsed.

```
//won't work
$(document).ready(init);
var init = function() {
   console.log('init not called');
}
```

Correct method:

```
//Works
var init = function() {
   console.log('document is ready');
}
$(document).ready(init);
```

Notice that $(document).ready(init) is placed at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i noticed that sometimes is problem with that, i wrote safe solution for that, which fix this problem.

```
// jquery plugin 'jquery.ready.fix.js'
// @author Szymon Działowski
;(function ($) {
    $.fn.ready.old || $(function (r) {
        r = $.fn.ready;
        $.fn.ready = function (fn) {    $.isReady ? fn() : r(fn);    };
        $.fn.ready.old = r;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

after that you can run code:

```
$(function () {alert('go')})
```

and it always fire alert.

PS: it is a technique called "duck punching" more about: http://www.paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Following Zakas' [The art of throwing JavaScript errors](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/03/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors/), I began to throw my own errors in JavaScript as an approach to finding JS issues.

But this approach unfortunately started causing the jQuery ready() functions to silently fail, for unrelated parts of the site. :(

I learned that the following are different:

```
throw new Error()
```

is different from

```
console.error()
```

So, I started to use console.error(), and I still got the red highlighting in the console.

Answer (score 0):

In my case **document.ready was not called because a html form was sent to server by Ajax request** and only part of document was recived - and document ready is not called after ajax request.

In consequence some buttons which were on that part that was reloaded was not binded to events .click() atc.. anymore because these buttons were new and binding of these events was called during document ready only first time - not for AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing above works another dirty trick is to wrap your function into to a SetTimeOut function without any time this simply queues the code to run once the current call stack is finished executing

```
     setTimeout(function(){
        FillOpenTranscriptionTasks();
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Just had this crop up and it turned out to be a spelling mistake in the script tag:

`<script type="text/javscript">`

Note the missing 'a' in javascript.  Changing to simply:

`<script>`

Fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this problem caused by an iframe with a self-closing tag.

This is good:

```
<iframe src="http://..."></iframe>
```

This is not, and causes all JS on the page to fail silently:

```
<iframe src="http://..." />
```

Answer (score -3):

instead of $( document ).ready( function() { ... } );

try

$( document ).ready( abc() );

function abc() {
 ....
}

worked for me.i myself searched lot of places, but couldn't find a solution. Tried this out randomly and worked!!

Comment: Unless your abc function returns a function this code does not do what you think. abc will execute and send the return value to $(document).ready(). If the return value is null, you might cause problems for others like I explained in my answer. You might as well just do abc(); or (function() {...})();

Answer (score -4):

I had such Problem, Just changed `<script type="text/javascript">` to `<script type="javascript">` and all problems gone!