# Unable to load js file from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created jquery functions and put them in a js file and called the file from my php using `<script src="newajax.js"></script>`.
This was working and now it has stopped working.
If i copy all my functions into the php file between the `<script></script>` tags, It works. I know there is not any issue with the js script.

To test I only added

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  alert("ready");
});
```

into the js file and called it from my php. It did not show the alert but when I did this inside the php file

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
       alert("ready");
    })    
</script>
```

It worked.

So I know there isn't any issue in the php file. It just looks like the script is not being picked up and it was before with exactly the same code. I have not removed the files to a different location. The js files are in the same directory as the php file.

Anybody encountered such an issue? Or know a reason why this could happen.
FYI - I know they are html tags but I have used php extension to be able to run php functions in my file.
The jquery.js file is loaded first before my js file.

When I loaded the webpage in a new tab, it worked. I was refreshing the same browser window when the .js script stopped being called.

Comment: have you check your browser console ?it shows any error ?

Comment: care to share  your JS file code?
It surely has a js error that will show in console if you keep console open while loading website

Comment: can you share your directory structure?

Comment: make sure its not conflicting .. check error console while you are adding in your js file ..

Comment: if you have already **document.ready** in your js file file, then put that function only which you want to do .. additionally, in firebug check whether you are getting any 404 related to this file.

Comment: also you need to make sure that, your **jquery.js** file should be loaded first and then after your **<script src="newajax.js"></script>** should be loaded.. so also take care of that

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857072/why-is-document-ready-not-firing-for-me

Comment: Check the network tab of inspect element is jquery library is actually loading ?

Comment: It's actually working now. I tested with different alert messages and it works. Very strange. @shivgre like i mentioned I copied the code between the script tags and it worked just not via the file.

Comment: Make sure `<script src="newajax.js"></script>` is placed after the jquery library loading script tag.

Comment: Make sure your jquery.js file should be loaded first then your newajax.js should be loaded or else it will give throw you an error. Care to share your Js file?

Comment: Ok, so it stopped loading again. Basically I am just reloading the same browser every time. When I opened a new browser window and entered the url it worked. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: @JayminsFakeAccount The issue is nothing to do with the content of the js file, it's that sometimes it does not pick up the js file from the php file. If I was making an error in the js file or if the question was code related then yes surely I would share the script but it's working and by looking into the content of the file would drag the post off topic.

Comment: have you included jquery in your php file?

Comment: make sure you have placed `newajax.js` in the correct path. you are using a relative reference path. Check the error report in browser console. And check the network tab in your browser console.